# PHP - Inheritance

Tags: php, oop, inheritance

I am currently learning OOP concepts. I have used CodeIgniter, I know it has OOP concepts but I don't understand how it works. I just use the methods in the documentation.

I am now on the inheritance part.

Here is my code:

```
<?php

class Artist {
    public $name;
    public $genre;
    public $test = 'This is a test string';

    public function __construct(string $name, string $genre) {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->genre = $genre;
    }
}

class Song extends Artist {
    public $title;
    public $album;

    public function __construct(string $title, string $album) {
        $this->title = $title;
        $this->album = $album;
    }

    public function getSongArtist() {
        return $this->name;
    }
}

$artist = new Artist('Joji Miller', 'Lo-Fi');
$song = new Song('Demons', 'In Tounges');

echo $song->getSongArtist(); // returns nothing
```

From what I understand inheritance will let me access properties and methods from  the parent class.

In my example I have instantiate the **Artist**. So now I have Joji Miller as artist name.

Now, if I instantiate the **Song** class, I thought that I can access the artist name since I am extending the **Artist** class. But it is just empty.

Would you help me understand why it is not getting the artist name?

Hope I explained myself clearly. Thankyou..

Comment: you do not need to instantiate the parent class. Just call the child class as it already extends the parent.

Comment: Song extends Artist ?   Sounds weird ;-)

Comment: *Is* a `Song` an `Artist`? Could you substitute a `Song` any place you'd use an `Artist`? … Then those two things have nothing in common and should not inherit each other.

Comment: hi @Akintunde007, Yes. But what if I want to add the artist name first? I am thinking that if I don't instantiate the parent class, my artist name would be blank. Is this right?

Comment: then in the construct function of the child class, call, `parent::__construct()`. Maybe pass the name and genre via the child class

Comment: Hi, please forgive. I am just new with the inheritance concept. I am using the wrong example. Maybe I need to learn when to use inheritance.

Comment: Indeed. Hint: not here. Practically speaking, you don't need inheritance all that often. Start simple without it. Add it later when you experience bottlenecks with *code reuse*; which is what inheritance is mostly about. Here you simply want three independent classes: `Song`, `Artist` and `Album`, and you *pass* them to each other in some order that makes sense. E.g.: `$ar = new Artist('Foo'); $al = new Album('Bar', $ar); $al->addSong(new Song('Baz', $ar));`

Comment: @deceze , thank you for clearing things. So they have nothing in common that is why I have to make separate classes for each. I will try more examples so I can fully understand it. And I didn't know that I can pass an instance of an object when you instantiate a new object. Learned something new :)

Comment: That is what OOP is all about: passing *objects* around instead of simple primitive values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because when defining the `Song` class's `__construct()` function you are overriding the Artist's `__contruct()`  function. Which is the function that gets called when you do `$song = new Song(...)`

Using the keyword `parent`:: you can access the parent's classes functions.

The following works.

```
<?php

class Artist {
    public $name;
    public $genre;
    public $test = 'This is a test string';

    public function __construct(string $name, string $genre) {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->genre = $genre;

    }

}

class Song extends Artist {
    public $title;
    public $album;

    public function __construct(string $title, string $album, string $ArtistName, string $genre) {
        $this->title = $title;
        $this->album = $album;

        parent::__construct($ArtistName, $genre);
    }

    public function getSongArtist() {
        return $this->name;
    }
}

$artist = new Artist('Joji Miller', 'Lo-Fi');
$song = new Song('Demons', 'In Tounges','Joji Miller', 'Lo-Fi');

echo $song->getSongArtist(); // returns nothing
```

Comment: Oh I see. You can call the construct function of the artist class inside the song class. That is the use of parent:: Thanks Fredster. I learned new things..

Comment: No problem. Exactly, that's how to use `parent::`. You can accept my answer as correct then! :)

Answer (score 9):

Heh. Learning "oop principles" from CodeIgniter is like going to North Korea to study democracy. And you have already learned the wrong things.

The `extends` keyword should be read as "is special case of". As in `class Admin extends User` means that the admin instance is a more specialized case of generic user.

And that's where you are wrong. Song is not a subtype of an artist.

Instead the song has an artist, which performs it. As in:

```
$artist = new Artist('Freddie Mercury');
$song = new Song('Another One Bites the Dust', $artist);

echo $song->getArtist()->getName();
```

Another bad practice, that you seem to have picked up: stop defining class variables as `public`. That breaks the encapsulation. Instead those values should be assigned using methods, because then you will e able top track, format and validate those values.

Comment: North Korea - 

Comment: Hehe. You are funny. Thankyou. I also have read about the visibility. Still learning when to use protected and private. I appreciate the tips.

Answer (score 5):

First of all in your case you have not the best example of inheritance...
And it leads to confusion...

I'd rather advise you to have in base class base behavior related to all descendants, like here.

Base class:

```
<?php

class SomethingWithName
{
    private $name;
    public function __construct(string $name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }
    public function getName(): string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
}
```

Your classes:

```
class Artist extends SomethingWithName
{
    private $genre;
    public function __construct(string $name, string $genre)
    {
        parent::__construct($name);
        $this->genre = $genre;
    }
    public function getGenre(): string
    {
        return $this->genre;
    }
}

class Song extends SomethingWithName
{
    private $album;
    private $artist;
    public function __construct(string $name, string $album, Artist $artist)
    {
        parent::__construct($name);
        $this->album = $album;
        $this->artist = $artist;
    }
    public function getAlbum(): string
    {
        return $this->album;
    }
    public function getArtist(): Artist
    {
        return $this->artist;
    }
}
```

Result:

```
$a = new Artist('Joji Miller', 'Lo-Fi');
$s = new Song('Demons', 'In Tounges', $a);
var_export([
    $s->getName(), // Demons
    $s->getAlbum(), // In Tounges
    $s->getArtist()->getName(), // Joji Miller
    $s->getArtist()->getGenre(), // Lo-Fi
]);
```

Comment: Hi Vladimir, thanks for the detailed answer. One question, is my understanding right that we need to use parent::__construct() if we have to call a property from a parent class? I have seen parent::__construct in CodeIgniter.

Comment: The `HasName` should be an interface and not a superclass.

Comment: @danangeloalcanar When your parent __construct method contains some stuff which you need to use in your child class (init some properties, etc) - then you have to call `parent::__construct()` in 9 out of 10 cases, but it always depends on particular implementation...

Comment: @tereško Yes, it sounds really reasonable to have interface `HasName`, but I didn't manage to find something else common between `Artist` and `Song` as base class, that's why decided to use this one to show concept of simple inheritance...